Help with a principal value integral
I need to integrate
$$\int_0^\rho {\left(1-\frac{2m}{r}\right)^{-1}\left[ \sqrt{\frac{2m}{r}}-k\left(k^2-1+\frac{2m}{r} \right)^{-1/2} \right]}dr$$
Here $0<k\le 1$ and $m>0$, and the upper limit $\rho>2m$.
When $k=1$ the integrand collapses into $\sqrt{r/2m}$ and it's a piece of cake. When $k\neq 1$, there is a $1/r$-shaped singularity at $r=2m$. Since the upper limit $\rho>2m$, I believe the integral is perfectly fine as a principal value, i.e.,
$$\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}{
\left\{
\int_0^{2m-\epsilon} {\left(1-\frac{2m}{r}\right)^{-1}\left[ \sqrt{\frac{2m}{r}}-k\left(k^2-1+\frac{2m}{r} \right)^{-1/2} \right]dr} 
+ 
\int_{2m+\epsilon}^\rho {\left(1-\frac{2m}{r}\right)^{-1}\left[ \sqrt{\frac{2m}{r}}-k\left(k^2-1+\frac{2m}{r} \right)^{-1/2} \right]dr}
\right\}
}
$$
The antiderivatives I get using https://www.integral-calculator.com/ are ridiculous. I am pretty sure the final PV integral -- as an antiderivative or with the limits inserted -- is very simple-looking, just slightly worse than the case $k=1$.
Can anybody help with this?

With respect to which variable are you integrating? $r$?

Yes, sorry - fixed it.

If $$I=\int{\left(1-\frac{2m}{r}\right)^{-1}\left[ \sqrt{\frac{2m}{r}}-k\left(k^2-1+\frac{2m}{r} \right)^{-1/2} \right]}\,dr$$
$$r=\frac{2 m}{t^2} \implies I=4m\int\Bigg(\frac{1}{t^2 \left(t^2-1\right)}-\frac{k}{t^3 \left(t^2-1\right)
   \sqrt{t^2+(k^2-1)}}  \Bigg)\,dt$$
$$\int \frac{dt}{t^2 \left(t^2-1\right)}=\frac 1t+\frac 12 \log \left(\frac{1-t}{1+t}\right)$$ The remaining integral
$$J=\int \frac{dt}{t^3 \left(t^2-1\right) \sqrt{t^2+(k^2-1)}}$$
is less pleasant but workable
$$2\,J=\frac{\sqrt{t^2+k^2-1}}{\left(k^2-1\right) t^2}+\frac{\left(2 k^2-3\right) \tan
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{k^2+t^2-1}}{\sqrt{1-k^2}}\right)}{\left
   (1-k^2\right)^{3/2}}+$$
$$\frac 1 k \log \left(k\frac{\sqrt{t^2+k^2-1}-k}{\sqrt{t^2+k^2-1}+k}\right)$$
Back to $r$
$$\color{blue}{I(r)=2  \sqrt{2m r}-4 m \coth ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{2m}{r}}\right)-\frac{k r \sqrt{k^2+\frac{2 m}{r}-1}}{k^2-1}}$$ $$\color{blue}{-\frac{2 k \left(2
   k^2-3\right) m \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{k^2+\frac{2
   m}{r}-1}}{\sqrt{1-k^2}}\right)}{\left(1-k^2\right)^{3/2}}+4 m
   \coth ^{-1}\left(\frac{k}{\sqrt{k^2+\frac{2 m}{r}-1}}\right)}$$
Now, it is perfectly workable. Usin Taylor, the finel result is
$$I(\rho)+\left(\frac{4 \left(k^2-2\right) m}{k^2-1}+\frac{8 k \left(2 k^2-3\right) m \tan
   ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{1-k}{1+k}}\right)}{\left(1-k^2\right)^{3/2}}+16 m \tanh
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{k-1}{k+1}\right)\right)-\frac{\left(k^4+3\right) \epsilon ^2}{16 k^4 m}+O\left(\epsilon ^4\right)$$
